# FastAPI, uvicorn.run() always create 3 instances, but I want it 1 instance

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I run FastAPI at PyCharm IDE and it always run 3 workers.
I don't know why, but, the last instance created is being accessed on every API call.

Could anyone can help how can I get single running worker?

Code:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
                   allow_origins=["*"],
                   allow_methods=["*"],
                   allow_headers=["*"])
print(f"main.py with :{app}")


@app.get('/')
def home():
    return "Hello"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=False, log_level="debug", debug=True,
                workers=1, limit_concurrency=1, limit_max_requests=1)
```

Console output:

> ```
> /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/bin/python /Users/user/github/my-project/backend/main.py
> main.py with :<fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x102b35d50>
> INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/user/github/my-project/backend']
> INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
> INFO:     Started reloader process [96259] using statreload
> main.py with :<fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x10daadf50>
> main.py with :<fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at 0x1106bfe50>
> INFO:     Started server process [96261]
> INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
> INFO:     Application startup complete.
> ```

Comment: Hi @John, why do you say that there are always 3 workers ? I don't see anything in the log. With multiple workers you would have a repetition of the last 3 "INFO"

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel-Lin, `main.py` was created and I thought it is because of 3 workers are running

Comment: Is it thread then? Do you know how to make it to be called only one time?
If I run command `uvicorn main:app --workers 1` then it only called one time though.

Comment: What do you mean by "`main.py` was created " ? I believe your configuration is already running on one single worker

Comment: Instances of `FastAPI()` were created 3 times as shown in the log.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to your last comment I understood better your question.

**Your real question**

So in fact your question is why is `FastAPI` object is created 3 times.

In the log one can indeed see that you have 3 different memory adresses `0x102b35d50`, `0x10daadf50`, `0x1106bfe50`

This doesn't mean that you have 3 workers, just that the `FastAPI` object is created 3 times. The last one this the one that your API will use.

**Why it happens**

The object is created multiple times, because :

1. First, you run `main.py` that go through the all code (one creation of `FastAPI` object), and then reach the `__main__`
2. Then `uvicorn` launch `main:app` so it go once again to the file `main.py` and build another `FastAPI` object.
3. The last one is created by the `debug=True` when you set it to False you have one less `FastAPI` object created. I'm not quite sure why.

**The solution**

The solution is to separate the API definition from the start of the API.

For example, one could create a `run.py` file with :

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=False, log_level="debug", debug=True,
                workers=1, limit_concurrency=1, limit_max_requests=1)
```

and launch this file.

Another option would be to launch your API in command line:

```
uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 --log-level=debug --limit-max-requests=1 --limit-concurrency=1
```

You can find all the command line arguments [here](https://www.uvicorn.org/)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a a lot in every aspect.

Comment: FYI, someone may get errors when including `debug=True` and `limit_concurrency=1`. For a simple `hello world` it's better to not have extra params.

Comment: There is also the 3rd option: initialize `app` within `if __name__ != "__main__":` (that is an equivalent of `else` branch from the example).